# How do you copy a machine instruction to a register by just using shift, or, ori?

Tags: mips32

I've been trying to learn assembly language (MIPS32) on my own, and I've been following this free online curriculum that teaches it.

There's an exercise that asks me to copy ori $8, $6, 0x20 into $9 by using only or, ori, and shift. Unfortunately, an answer isn't provided, and I have no idea how to do this. Can somebody help me or point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to inspect the format used for the `ori` instruction:

```
0011 01ss ssst tttt iiii iiii iiii iiii
```

<sub>Source: [MIPS Instruction Reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html)</sub>

- `sssss` the destination register which is `$8 = 01000`
- `ttttt` the source register which is `$6 = 00110`
- `ii...` the immediate operand which is `0x20 = ...10 0000`

The resulting instruction looks as follows:

```
0011 01ss ssst tttt iiii iiii iiii iiii
0011 0101 0000 0110 0000 0000 0010 0000
```

Which we convert to hexadecimal for use in our code: `0x35060020`

Since the `ori` instruction accepts 16 bits for an immediate operand we can combine it with a simple left-shift to populate the higher 16 bits first with `0x3506` and then add the lower 16 bits with another `ori` instruction.

```
ori $9, $0, 0x3506 # insert upper 16 bits of instruction
# 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 0101 0000 0110

sll $9, $9, 0x10   # shift 16 bits to higher part of register
# 0011 0101 0000 0110 0000 0000 0000 0000

ori $9, $9, 0x0020 # insert lower 16 bits of instruction
# 0011 0101 0000 0110 0000 0000 0010 0000
```